# Buttons that give out the role

Tags: python, discord.py

How to add 2 buttons to this embed so that when you click on the button, the role is given to the person who sent the photo?

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return

    if message.channel.id == 1089250195042214039:
        if message.attachments:
            attachment_url = message.attachments[0].url
            admin_channel = client.get_channel(1065572523548344381)
            
            class RoleRequestView(discord.ui.View):
                def __init__(self, user):
                    super().__init__(timeout=None)
                    self.user = user
                    self.add_item(discord.ui.Button(label="stable", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, custom_id="stable_button"))
                    self.add_item(discord.ui.Button(label="nightly", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, custom_id="nightly_button"))
            
            view = RoleRequestView(message.author)
            embed = discord.Embed(title="[Send photo] Role request ~ ", description=f"Requester: {message.author.mention}")
            embed.set_image(url=attachment_url)
            
            await admin_channel.send(embed=embed, view=view)

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

When I tried, the buttons just wouldn't show up

Comment: Hi. What button are you talking about?

Comment: @ClementGenninasca I updated the code in the theme, I would like the "stable" button to give out a certain role and the "nightly" button to do the same

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this if I'm not wrong:

```py
class RoleRequestView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, member: discord.Member):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.member = member
    @discord.ui.Button(label="stable", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, custom_id="stable_button"):
        role = get(self.member.server.roles, name="Stable_role")
        await self.member.add_roles(role)
    @discord.ui.Button(label="nightly", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, custom_id="nightly_button"):
        role = get(self.member.server.roles, name="Nightly_role")
        await self.member.add_roles(role)
```